# Android disable onClick toolbar overFlowIcon

Tags: android

It is simple information question. According to page situation i want to block user click on toolbar overflowIcon. I look for methods but cannot find a way. How can i disable onClick on OverflowIcon ?

Comment: can´t you just leave the onClick event function empty?

Comment: I cannot reach onClick event function

Comment: Why not can´t you overwrite it? What am I missing here?

Comment: I reach toolbars onClick method it doesn't affect OverflowIcon click. I cannot reach overflowIcon onClick method

Comment: I am sorry I don´t get your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Do you want disable all option menu or just one/two ?

Comment: I want to disable icon on toolbar

Comment: Do you have any menu icons in public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { ..............return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); }

Comment: May I know at where you need to disable it in Activity / Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to disable it in **ACTIVITY, Don't use** this lines,

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

If it is in **FRAGMENT**, Use

***setHasOptionsMenu(false);***    // inside of onCreateView

***Let you consider, You have 3 icons (Home,Search,LogOut).***

You don't want to show 1st icon in any fragment but have to show the 2nd & 3rd means,

**setHasOptionsMenu(true);**    // inside of onCreateView

AND 
Create a following method in Fragment,

```
  @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.home).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.search).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);  
    }
```

**Refer this :**

http://kiddyandroid.blogspot.in/2016/03/fragment.html